# How to output a one-dimensional array variable changing position every iteration

Tags: java, arrays

To start off- this is an assignment I am currently working on and am only looking to be pointed in the right direction- not have my work done for me.

I am trying to create a "tortoise and the hare" race by using a one dimensional array for positions down the track, using Thread.sleep(1000) so that the user can actually watch the race, and SecureRandom to generate a new number which corresponds to a predetermined forward or backward position change every iteration of a for loop (one second = one iteration = one new position on the track).

My problem is I have no idea where to start with printing out the physical position of the racers. We have to create a dotted line and place the racers on their respective current lateral position, which is changing every second until they win. I have no code to show for this portion of the program, as I have no idea where to start. I couldnt find any information related to this, can one of you point me in the right direction for this?

I apologize if I wasted anybody's time with the question. Thanks

Comment: Just start by for loop and sample print any sample word every second and then go forward (just step by step)

Comment: You need to learn java

Comment: with printing out the physical position you can create a `char[]` with a value of dots then loop each dot everytime position changes

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks for the help- Im aware I have a ways to go but I'm just starting the language so every bit helps

Answer (score 1):

You might try something like this:

```
public void printRacerPositions(double harePos, double tortoisePos, double trackLength)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < (harePos / trackLength) * VISUAL_TRACK_LENGTH; i++)
    {
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
    System.out.println("H");

    for(int i = 0; i < VISUAL_TRACK_LENGTH; i++)
    {
        System.out.print("-");
    }
    System.out.println("|");

    for(int i = 0; i < (tortoisePos / trackLength) * VISUAL_TRACK_LENGTH; i++)
    {
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
    System.out.println("T");
}
```

I didn't understand what you meant by a "one-dimensional array variable" that "changes position" as that doesn't really make any sense.  Honestly, I don't feel like you need to use an array to solve this problem at all.

You can just update the tortoise and hare's positions every iteration based on their speed and the random number generator you have, and then print out their positions visually as demonstrated above.

Note, you would have to define a

```
private int final VISUAL_TRACK_LENGTH; //The horizontal visual size of your track
```

somewhere for this to work.  The

```
(harePos / trackLength) * VISUAL_TRACK_LENGTH
```

calculation will get you the percentage of the race the hare has completed and then multiply it by the actual visual length of the track in characters, so that your actual track length can be anything, even if it wouldn't fit on your monitor.

Comment: I did end up doing something similar to your suggestion but I had to stick with arrays unfortunately per the assignment, I just made an array for each racer and ran a loop in the output method. It was a confusing question, I know. While I know the elements can't just bounce around I had been trying to say the printed variables change lateral position in the output screen to simulate a track race. I just didn't describe it well